# How to convert Json to Html in yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Is there some way in yesod-0.9.3 to convert `Json` to `Html` to include it into `<script/>` tag?

Using `Yesod.Json` and `Data.Aeson` I can get the value of a `Json` type, which I want to use as the value of a variable introduced in a `<script>` tag, that is, not to return `RepJson`, but to include it as a part of `RepHtml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fully qualified names...

```
let txtVal = Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding.decodeUtf8 $ Data.Aeson.encode jsonVal
```

then, inside your hamlet:

```
<script>
  var v = #{txtVal}
```

Note that this is a bit dangerous in that it doesn't check that the encoding was successful.  Look at the `Data.Text.Encoding` module for more info.